# RegEx Search in Coda to find missing <ul> tags

Tags: html, regex, coda

I'm repairing a broken website for a local municipality where there are rogue `<li>, <dd>, <dt>` (you name it) tags with no start-tags.

I'm no RegEx expert by any means and I'm looking for a possible search query in Coda (which allows regex searches) to find any group of list items for example that aren't wrapped in `<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>`.

Any thoughts out there? Wild cards are allowed (*) works for our example here.

Many thanks,
**Jason**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no, I don't think there's a way you can really do that in a regex (at least, not with certainty -- HTML and regex just don't mix).  You're probably better off using [The W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Okay thanks for that. Found a nice little tool that let me do validation on the entire site: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/